# Combine optional handler and parameter in Razor Page route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, routes, razor-pages

I have a page "/visits". Outputs a list of visits.
When clicking any visit, i need to navigate to "/visits/10", where "10" is the visit's id.
This is the easy part.
Now comes other "CRUD" operations, that is "Create" for now. I want "/visits/create" to be used for creation.

What do i have now:

1. "Visits.cshtml" razor page and model
2. "Visit.cshtml" razor page, which i want to use as a "edit" and "create" page at the same time.

I tried customizing "page" directive for "Visit.cshtml" like this:

```
@page "/visits/{handler?}/{id?}"
```

And this is the model:

```
public class VisitModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public int VisitId { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public CrudMode CrudMode { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int id)
    {
        CrudMode = CrudMode.Update;
        VisitId = id;
    }

    public void OnGetCreate()
    {
        CrudMode = CrudMode.Create;
    }
}
```

The way i understand this is that "handler" parameter is optional and when navigating to this page without specifing it, default "event" is called (which is OnGet()).

But currently:

1. "/visits/10" i get my "OnGet" event, but "Id" value is 0 (default)
2. "/visits/create" i get my "OnGetCreate" event
3. "/visits/create/10" i still get my "OnGetCreate" event, which is logical, but i want to prohibit this
4. "/visits/anythingelse/10" i get my "OnGet" event and correct "Id" value

While googling i found a lot of info about optional handlers and optional parameters, but nothing about their combination, which led me to think i'm doing something weird. Perhaps i can manage this if i create separate pages for "edit" and "create" modes, but i don't want this, since i'll have to duplicate a lot of layouts. Of course, i can create a partial view or a view component in this case, but it seems to be a little overkill for such a simple task.

And also i would like to avoid altering app conventions (i.e. using AddRazorPagesOptions).

So essentially the question is how to properly combine optional handlers and optional parameters in this case? So that at least "OnGet" get's a correct parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are over-complicating things (polite-speak for "doing something weird). You will end up with a PageModel that looks like an MVC controller with too many actions/handlers, which is what Razor Pages is designed to avoid. You are fighting against Razor Pages, which is why you are having problems.

Separate pages for Create and Edit is the way to go, and partials are ideal for the duplicated parts of the CRUD form.

Comment: Well, i expected something like that. Perhaps if Razor pages wouldn't support handlers at all i wouldn't try to use them and use partials in the first place.